# Adding scrollbars to TextArea with fixed height

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex3

I have a TextArea that I want to give a fixed height to, and have scrollbars appear if the text overflows that height.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
    <mx:TextArea
        height="34"
        text="Line 1&#13;Line 2&#13;Line 3&#13;Line 4&#13;Line 5&#13;Line 6&#13;Line 7"/>
</mx:Application>
```

However, if I give it a height, no scrollbars appear (though I can scroll the text with the mousewheel or by selecting text). Even forcing scrollbars to always appear using `verticalScrollPolicy="on"` doesn't work.

Comment: @JasonTowne I didn't think overflow-y is relevant to a flex application?

Comment: You're absolutely right. I should have checked that question more carefully before linking to it. That will teach me to comment before I've had coffee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source for TextArea, you can see that the verticalScrollPolicy is hardcoded to be OFF if less than or equal to 40 pixels:

```
override public function get verticalScrollPolicy():String
{
    return height <= 40 ? ScrollPolicy.OFF : _verticalScrollPolicy;
}
```

You have a few options:

- Set the TextArea height to 41 or greater
- Create a custom control that inherits mx TextArea and override this method:

  ```
  override public function get verticalScrollPolicy():String
  {
      return _verticalScrollPolicy;
  }
  ```
- Use the Spark TextArea instead and use the property `heightInLines`

I found the answer in the following thread: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/flexcoders/message/112148